# How to write a join query which accepts placeholders (query params) using couchbasetemplate from Spring Data Couchbase 4.X version

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I need to get a set of data from 2 collections.

```
Employee
{"id":"1234",
"name":"Smith"}

Salary{
"employeeId":"1234",
"Salary":"10000"}
```

I am creating an utility method where I have to fetch the data by joining these two tables and pass the employeeId as param to the N1ql query.

So I am trying to use CouchbaseTemplate.findByQuery from Spring data couchbase 4.3.2.

There is no much documentation available on internet how to achieve this without creating a repository. What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

create a query for the matching(query) method :

```
Query specialUsers = new Query(QueryCriteria.where("firstname").equals("Taylor"));
final List<User> foundUsers = couchbaseTemplate.findByQuery(User.class).withConsistency(REQUEST_PLUS)
        .inCollection(collectionName).matching(specialUsers).all();
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference two collections in a single query, an @Query must be used.

template and generated repository queries can only reference one collection.

Comment: Could you merge this with your last answer? I am not sure there is a need for more than one post from one person (unless you are presenting two different ways of solving the problem).

Comment: They are two different solutions. One is the preferred way (matching)- but it won't work for the OP's case as they are doing a join across collections.